# OOP Design: Where to put model serialization logic?

Tags: oop

Let's say that I have an `car` object, which contains `type`, `model`, `color`, ... attributes.

Now, after retrieving the object from database, I want to do something to change its attributes to another set of values. Something like this:

```
{
  type: car.type.upcase,
  model: car.model + "-BMW",
  color: car.color + 3
}
```

My question is, where should I put this logic? Should I define a method inside the model class

```
class Car
  def serialize
    #
  end
end
```

and then call `car.serialize`.
Or should I create another layer (says `CarSerializer` class):

```
class CarSerializer
  def self.transform(car)
    # 
  end 
end
```

and use `CarSerializer.transform(car)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the [DTO or Data Transfer Objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). These are

> simple objects that should not contain any business logic but may contain serialization and deserialization mechanisms for transferring data

### Comparison

If you are not looking for a DTO then it may be useful to look at pros and cons for each approach and compare that to your current business case.

#### Serialization in Data Object Class

Pros

- Complete [encapsulation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) of the data. I.e. The data class has full control over how data is used/transformed/displayed.
- When changing the structure of the class, by adding or removing attributes, one would not have to change other functions in other classes as all serialization methods are right there in the same class.

Cons

- if the serialization/transformation process itself requires a lot of processing and other classes, then keeping the functionality inside the data object class can become complicated

#### External Serialization Class

Pros

- Keeps object class clean. All complex transformations and date calculations/formats are exported to a secondary class. This could be similar to the [bridge design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)
- A single serialization class could be used to serialize multiple different classes. Perhaps you could serialize a Car and Plane class with the same `VehicleSerializer.transform()` method.
- One can have multiple serialization methods. Say you want to serialize to both JSON and XML, then it would be easier to make use of a separate class.

Cons

- If you want to add or change an attribute then you need to also maintain the transformer classes.

---

### My Suggestion

Unless you plan on doing crazy transformation algorithms or multiple different serializations (XML/JSON), I would stick with keeping the serialization in the Car class itself.

This way you keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: thanks @Shell Code. I have personal preferences for functional programming so at first I did want to go with the second approach.
But what you suggest is also very reasonable. I think I will look at the business logic to make the decision. Thanks